# how to perform the same subsetting process on several dataframes *in-place* in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

i'm looking for a way to quickly perform **in-place** subsetting of my dataframes in R.

say i have n dfs of varying lengths, all containing 3 columns: `chr`, `start`, `end` describing genomic regions altogether.

I created a vector of the legitimate 'chr' labels for that matter, let's say ["chr1", "chr2", ... , "chr12"].

some (or all) of my dfs has rows which contains invalid chromosomal names (e.g. *"chr4_UG5432_random"* or *"chrX"*. the names doesn't really matter - just that they don't appear in my vector of "valid" labels), and I want to efficiently filter out rows with this invalid labels.

so the best solution I found so far is putting them all in a list, and using `lapply` on them with

`subset(df,chr %in% c(paste0("chr",1:12)))`

and I understand that afterwards I can use the functions `list2env` to retrieve the variables "holding" the modified dfs.

but i'm sure there is a much simpler way to perform this filtering in-place for each dataframe, without having to throw them in a list.
any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example including code, input and expected output as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Can `chr4_UG5432_random` be in any of the columns or in a certain column? And is `chr4_UG5432_random` part of a string or is a value in the column?

Comment: Actually, per this [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451): *best practice is to avoid having a bunch of [similarly structured] data.frames not in a list*!

Comment: replying to you @TarJae:
the `chr4_UG5432_random` is just a made up example for rows I currently wish to avoid, and they may appear *only* in the 'chr' column.
the other two (start & end) are numrical.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
You can store all your desired strings to filter in a dataframe like for example:

```
df_to_avoid <- data.frame(chr = c("chr4_XXX", "chr4_YYY", "chr3ZZZ"))
```

then use:

```
dplyr::filter(df1, !chr %in% df_to_avoid$chr)
```

So you can filter by multiple strings!!
data new:

```
df1 <- tribble( 
  ~chr, ~start, ~end,
  "chr1", 10, 20,
  "chr1", 1, 10,
  "chr2", 20, 30, 
  "chr3ZZZ", 4, 16, 
"chr4_XXX", 324, 343)
```

output new:

```
  chr   start   end
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 chr1     10    20
2 chr1      1    10
3 chr2     20    30
```

**First answer**

We could use `filter` with negative `grepl` by `!`

```
dplyr::filter(df1, !grepl('chr4_XXX', chr))
```

Output:

```
  chr   start   end
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 chr1     10    20
2 chr1      1    10
3 chr2     20    30
4 chr3      4    16
```

data:

```
df1 <- tribble( 
  ~chr, ~start, ~end,
  "chr1", 10, 20,
  "chr1", 1, 10,
  "chr2", 20, 30, 
  "chr3", 4, 16, 
"chr4_XXX", 324, 343)
```